# mysql select date inside a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following columns:

- date_start | date_end
- 2013-01-14 | 2013-01-16
- 2013-01-16 | 2013-03-18
- 2013-01-22 | 2013-03-21
- 2013-02-02 | 2013-02-10
- 2013-03-25 | 2013-03-28

i need to create a sql statment that I can filter these record with

date_start:  2013-01-17  date_end:2013-03-22

and the found results to be:

- date_start | date_end
- 2013-01-16 | 2013-03-18
- 2013-01-22 | 2013-03-21
- 2013-02-02 | 2013-02-10

does anyone know how to do this?

thank you

Comment: This is an issue of determining if date ranges overlap.  See [this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap/325964#325964

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select * from your_table where date_start >=  '2013-01-17'
                          and   date_end   <=  '2013-03-22'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date_start BETWEEN '2013-01-17' AND '2013-03-22'
  AND date_end BETWEEN '2013-01-17' AND '2013-03-22'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_start` > '2013-01-17' && `date_end` < '2013-03-22'
```

You will need to replace `table` with your actual table name in your database.